# Making data out of one point in multiple csv files in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a variable out of a single point in 5 different data tables.

ie. I have data for mental disorders for each year in seperate CSV files. How do I track just one variable (eg Autism) in each file and put it into one variable?

Here is what I have so far:

```
d2000 <- read.table("C:/AL00.csv")
d2001 <- read.table("C:/AL01.csv")
d2002 <- read.table("C:/AL02.csv")
d2003 <- read.table("C:/AL03.csv")

rownames(d2000) <- d2000[,3]
rownames(d2001) <- d2001[,3]
rownames(d2002) <- d2002[,3]
rownames(d2003) <- d2003[,3]

ASD = c(d2000["Autism","Total"],d2001["Autism","Total"],d2002["Autism","Total"])
```

This isn't working. I tried typing in just one of the data points:

```
>d2000["Autism","Total"]
[1] 2,763
Levels: 1,075 1,480 2,763
```

It outputs the correct number, but what are these "Levels"? Are they my problem, if so, how would I fix?

Comment: Try setting `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in read.table.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do (some examples of your data may help), but the reason you're getting those "levels" is because you imported a csv file where the numbers are formatted with commas. Excel, I presume? Remove all formatting from your sheet before exporting it.

Comment: Your numbers are interpreted as strings. This is caused by the fact that your numbers use a `,` to either separate thousands, or it is used as a decimal character. I agree with @HongOoi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
ll <- lapply(list.files(pattern="AL[0-9]+.*csv",full.names=TRUE),
             function(x) read.table(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
res <- do.call(rbind,ll)[,'Autism']
```

This will give you the column Autism in on vector. Then to convert it to a numeric you can do some regular expressions:

```
as.numeric(gsub(',','',res))
```